# How can I get a view like this using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello guys how can I get a view like this link, it has to be scrollable from vertical and horizontal, I started doing it with recyclerview and it works horizontally but how can I make it to work vertically.

Link of the view to acomplish
https://i.stack.imgur.com/puxEi.png

This is the code for the layouts am using fragments and replacing those on the framelayouts because the test requires me to do so.

--activity main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/section1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/section2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

----section1 and section2 code are the same

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="fragments.SectionOne"
    android:background="#f2f2f2">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If use scrollview and wrap all this under a single framelayout both sections are overlapping each other

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/section1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/section2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: they are 3 Horizontal RecyclerViews and wrap the entire layout into a ScrollView or NestedScrollView if you found issues in scrolling

Comment: If @Zain comment doesn't help, please post your code and your attempts to implement this.

Comment: Hello @BrentGeorge I added the layout that I am using and the thing is because of this test requires me to use fragments for any advise thank you.

Comment: Hello @Zain I added the layout code am using for any advice thank you.